# @composable invocations can only happen from the context of an @composable function for Composable with LaunchedEffect and AndroidViewBinding

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewbinding

I have a composable function

```
@Composable
fun SomeComposeView(){
     
    AndroidViewBinding(SomefragactBinding::inflate) {
        val myFragment = fragmentContainerView.getFragment<SomeFragment>()
      myFragment.somefunction()  
   }
```

I want to call it only once so I am trying this in my Activity

```
binding.SomeComposeViewLayout.setContent {
             OwnTheme() {
                 LaunchedEffect(Unit){
                    SomeComposeView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a function inside the fragment like myFragment.somefunction() It gets called twice, I want to ensure its called only once so I am trying to use LaunchedEffect how can we call the function only once

However I am getting the error `@composable invocations can only happen from the context of an @composable function`

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve ?

LaunchedEffect is a composable function but it a provide a coroutine context inside not a composable context so the error is legit. You can't call a composable function inside a launchedEffect

Comment: I have a function  inside the fragment like myFragment.somefunction() It gets called twice, I want to ensure its called only once so I am trying to use LaunchedEffect  how can we call the function only once

Comment: I have changed the question the function is called within AndroidViewBinding  itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The LaunchedEffect error

You can't call a composable inside a [LaunchedEffect](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#launchedeffect). According to documentation, LaunchedEffect is meant to run suspend functions in the scope of a composable but not to render a composable.

To avoid your error you simply have to remove the LaunchedEffect an call your composable directly:

```kotlin
binding.SomeComposeViewLayout.setContent {
             OwnTheme() {
                
                    SomeComposeView()
               
            }
        }
    }
```

#### AndroidViewBinding interop

The [AndroidViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/viewinterop/package-summary#AndroidViewBinding(kotlin.Function3,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function1)) composable has 3 parameters :

- The inflater
- A modifier
- A callback on update.

You placed the call of `myFragment.somefunction()`in the update block without any conditions so it will run at each recomposition.

#### Solution 1: Using a state

Create a boolean state that tells you if you need to call `myFragment.somefunction()`

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SomeComposeView(){
    
var needToCallSomeFunction by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

AndroidViewBinding(SomefragactBinding::inflate) {
        val myFragment = fragmentContainerView.getFragment<SomeFragment>()
    if(needToCallSomeFunction) {
        myFragment.somefunction()
        needToCallSomeFunction = false
    }
   }

}
```

#### Solution 2: Call it in factory

You could create the viewBinding in the factory and before returning it, using it to get your fragment and call your function :

```kotlin
    AndroidViewBinding(
        factory = { inflater, parent, attachToParent ->
            SomefragactBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, attachToParent).also {
                it.fragmentContainerView.getFragment<SomeFragment>().somefunction()
            }
        }
    )
```

Because it is in the factory, it will just run once

Comment: Thanks , but this is ridiculous on Part of Android what should be a normal functionality has to be a workaround

Comment: I edited my answer, I think you can call it in the factory. Tell me if the second solution suits you.

Comment: This error occured to me when I tried to put Image() inside of my Canvas()